# How to get sum of rupees of current year and previous year withine single query?

Tags: mysql

I want to select sum of current year rupees and previous year rupees material wise. Following is my table fields:

```
   |Material_Number|Material_name|Date      |Rupees   |
   |1              |abc          |2014-02-01|1.20,000 |
   |1              |abc          |2014-02-02|50,000   |
   |1              |abc          |2013-05-05|1,50,000 |
   |5              |pqr          |2012-01-05|20,000   |
   |2              |xyz          |2013-05-04|10,000   |
   |2              |xyz          |2014-01-04|10,100   |
   ----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to to display material wise sum of rupees of current year and previous year. following is my table structure that i want:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------
  |Previous_Year_sum| Material_name|Current Year_sum|
  --------------------------------------------------- 
  |1,20,000         | abc          | 1,50,000       |
  ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You *are* storing money as DECIMAL, right?

Comment: Yes i can use money in decimal format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this use `SUM()` with `CASE` condtions

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(`Date`) = YEAR(NOW()) -1 THEN
    REPLACE (Rupees, ',', '')
    ELSE 0 END )
Previous_Year_sum,
Material_name,
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(`Date`) = YEAR(NOW()) THEN
REPLACE (Rupees, ',', '')
    ELSE 0 END )current_year
FROM `Table1`
GROUP BY Material_name
```

[**See Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/871b3/3)

Comment: @Kamlesh update your question with table definitions and their relation

Answer (score 0):

```
select YEAR(Date) as year , SUM(rupees), material_name from test group by material_name, year;
```

Comment: A little explaination wouldn't harm.

Comment: @nkn hardly necessary for such a trivial problem

Comment: My query sums up the cost of materials year wise .. but is not showing the output in the format the question demands.